# Adding an isolated point to a Borel space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a Borel space $S$, which is basically a Borel subset of a Polish space. I want to add an isolated point $\alpha$ to $S$. Let $\overline{S}=S\bigcup \{\alpha\}$. Can I say that $S$ is clopen in $\overline{S}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $\{\alpha\}$ is closed, so $S$ is open in $\overline{S}$.

And $\{\alpha\}$ is isolated, which means it's an open set in $\overline{S}$. Hence $S$ is closed in $\overline{S}$ as well.

Comment: I guess your reasoning in concluding that \{\alpha\} is a closed set in $\overline{S}$ is that $\overline{S}$ is a metric space and hence Hausdorff.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Bora yes, indeed. Singletons are closed in all metric spaces.